# ¿Cómo accedo a este tipo de clases en Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class

Estoy trabajando con la herramienta SAP Conversational que crea chatbots, el punto es que al crearlo, me genera un script para insertar el chatbot a mi pagina, el script me crea un div con varios elementos dentro, el problema es que hay un div al que quiero acceder que es:

```
<div class="RecastAppExpander CaiAppExpander open">
```

En mi js estoy intentando acceder de esta manera para realizar una accion al hacerle click:

```
 $(".RecastAppExpander CaiAppExpander open").click(function(){
      alert("Hello World");
})
```

Pero no funciona de esa manera, nunca vi un class con palabras separadas entonces no se si se accede de diferente manera. Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Tienes que por fuerza llamar a las 3 clases para invocar al selector? Ya probaste usando solo una clase?

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres hacer match por varias clases en el mismo elemento, cada clase tiene que ir con punto adelante y sin espacios en el selector:

```js
$(".RecastAppExpander.CaiAppExpander.open").click(function(){ alert("Hello World"); })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="RecastAppExpander CaiAppExpander open">Hola</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

el problema en tu codigo es la manera de llamar las clases multiplas, es decir .. el selector que tienes es `.RecastAppExpander CaiAppExpander open` y realmente tendria que quedar de la siguiente manera : `.RecastAppExpander.CaiAppExpander.open"`

eso porque las clases multiplas funcionan al igual que *css* es decir se encadenan gracias al selector `.` al dejar el espacio como has echo lo que jQuery lee es que hay un tag `CaiAppExpander` que esta al interno de un `node` que tiene como clase `RescastAppExpander` y lo mismo vale para la clase `open`.

otros tipos de encadenados en el selector puede ser un id con una clase ej : `#idElemento.clase`.

en tu caso el codigo tendria que quedar asi :

```js
$(".RecastAppExpander.CaiAppExpander.open").click(function(){
    alert("hola mundo!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="RecastAppExpander CaiAppExpander open">click me</div>
```

espero que te sea de ayuda, exitos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el ***selector*** por clase de jQuery $(".clase-1.clase-2")

En tu ejercicio cuando quieres hacer referencia a una clase tienes que hacer referencia a ella con el punto (.) seguido del nombre de la clase, te faltó eso.

**¡Ojo!** las clases están sin espacio entre los nombres, esto se debe a un tema de CSS cuando son descendientes o clases hermanas, pero puedes lograr tu resultado con el siguiente código:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="RecastAppExpander CaiAppExpander open">click me</div>
```

*(es agnóstico al elemento HTML que estés usando, mientras tengas ese elemento tenga esas clases)*

```
<button class="RecastAppExpander CaiAppExpander open">click</button>
```

**JS:**

```
$(".RecastAppExpander.CaiAppExpander.open").on('click', function(){ alert("Hello World");})
```